# Why is withWeekOfWeekyear giving me a different offset?

Tags: java, jodatime, jsr310

I'm trying to convert withWeekOfWeekyear over to java.time. I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting a different offset with withWeekOfWeekyear compared to weekOfWeekBasedYear.

```
    DateTime dateTimeWeek = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(1);
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTimeWeek = OffsetDateTime.now().with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 1);

    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now();

    System.out.println(dateTimeWeek); // 2016-01-04T12:20:50.981-05:00
    System.out.println(offsetDateTimeWeek); // 2016-01-04T12:20:51.034-04:00

    System.out.println(dateTime); // 2016-07-18T12:20:51.101-04:00
    System.out.println(offsetDateTime); // 2016-07-18T12:20:51.101-04:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`org.joda.time.DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) is time-zone aware.

> A `DateTime` calculates its fields with respect to a [`time zone`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html).

[`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) is *not* time-zone aware, i.e. does not adjust for Daylight Savings Time.

> `OffsetDateTime` adds to the instant the offset from UTC/Greenwich, which allows the local date-time to be obtained. `ZonedDateTime` adds full time-zone rules.

[`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) *is* time-zone aware, so if you use that, you should get same result.

> `ZonedDateTime` is an immutable representation of a date-time with a time-zone.